# filter product that availabel in inventory

Tags: laravel

my model is :

```php
product =>  
    id  
    ...  
store=>  
    product_id  
    quantity  
    is_come // for detect that is income product or this product sell
```

now how i can write query (eloquent builder) without turn into collection that filter product that sum of `is_come = true` bigger than `is_come = false` something i write that its wrong plz help me

```
if (request('isAvailable')){
    $data = $data->whereHas('store',function ($q){
        $q->when(true, function ($a){
            return $a->where('is_come', false)->sum('quantity')
                > $a->where('is_come', true)->sum('quantity');
        });
    });
}
```

or something like this

```
$data = $data->whereHas('store', function ($q){
            $q->where(function ($a) {
                return $a->where('store.is_come', 1)
                    ->sum('quantity');
            },
                '>'
                , function ($a) {
                    return $a->where('store.is_come', 0)->sum('quantity');
                  });
        });
```

`$data` is Product model instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the product ids matching the condition from the Store model first and then use that in your query.

```
$storeIds = Store::select('product_id', 
    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN store.is_come = 1 THEN quantity END) AS sum_1'),
    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN store.is_come = 0 THEN quantity END) AS sum_0'),
)->whereRaw('sum_1 > sum_0')->get()->pluck('product_id');

$data = Product::whereHas('store',function ($q) use ($storeIds){
    $q->whereIn('id', $storeIds);
})->get();
```

The code is not tested, but hope you got the idea.

Comment: thanks for help i test it and get this error ```Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sum_1' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `product_id`, SUM(CASE WHEN store.is_come = 1 THEN quantity END) as sum_1, SUM(CASE WHEN store.is_come = 0 THEN quantity END) as sum_0 from `store` where sum_1 > sum_0)```

Answer (score 0):

i found a way for that solution but i want an eloquent builder query way for my solution 
tanks for @Ahmed-shefeer

```
$storeProductIds = Store::select('product_id',
            DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN store.is_come = 1 THEN quantity END) AS sum_1'),
            DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN store.is_come = 0 THEN quantity END),0) AS sum_0')
        )->groupBy('product_id')->havingRaw('sum_1 - sum_0>0')->get()->pluck('product_id')->toArray();
        $data = Product::whereHas('store', function ($q) use ($storeProductIds) {
            $q->whereIn('product.id', $storeProductIds);
        })->get();
```